# How efficient is searching by tags?

Tags: mongoose

**Situation:**

I have 1 million users and I want to search them by tags.

**Here's the schema:**

```
const Account = new Schema({
  tags: { type: [String], default: ['cats'] }
})
```

**Here's the first query:**

```
const query = { tags: 'cats'}
const fields = { _id: 0 }
const options = { skip: 0, limit: 5 }

Account.find(query, fields, options)
```

After calling `find` method `Mongoose` will start searching and return the first 5 entries it matches. The performance in this case is optimal.

**Here's the second query:**

```
const query = { tags: 'cats'}
const fields = { _id: 0 }
const options = { skip: 500 000, limit: 5 }

Account.find(query, fields, options)
```

What going on in this case is of interest to me.

Does `Mongoose` match 500 000 entries first and then returns the next 5 entries?

Or does it somehow 'jump' to the 500 000 element without having to match them all beforehand?

I'm trying to understand how efficient this proccess is and whether I can improve it somehow. Do you have any advice?

Comment: find works same like "select", so it first of all matches 500,000 entries and then skip it so obviously performance wise its not good. You should search about indexing techniques or organize the data efficiently first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is matching 500,000 entries first.

From the MongoDB Definitive Guide 2nd Edition:

> $skip takes a number, n, and discards the first n documents from the result set.  As with “normal” querying, it isn’t efficient for large skips, as it must find all of the matches that must be skipped and then discard them.

You can examine your query in detail from the Mongo shell using explain():

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Ex:

```
// Create a dummy collection
var tagTypes = ['cats', 'dogs', 'chickens']
    for (i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
        let tag = tagTypes[Math.floor(Math.random()*tagTypes.length)]
        db.people.insert({"tags" : [tag]})
    }
```

then explain it

```
db.people.find({"tags" : "cats"}).skip(100).limit(10).explain("executionStats”)
```

totalDocsExamined is showing you that it is matching everything that it's skipping

```
"executionStats" : {
...
    "totalDocsExamined" : 420
```

If you were to create an index on tags:

```
db.people.ensureIndex({ "tags" : 1 })
```

Running it again you'd get:

```
"executionStats" : {
...
    "totalDocsExamined" : 110
```

Comment: thank you, sir! I awarded another user with the bounty by mistake. This answer deserves it. Sorry

Comment: No problem happy to help

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. My understanding is that `Find`here is very similar in query functionalities to `Select`, wherein it will work inefficiently by first going through 500,000 values before skipping them.

Hence, what I suggested is implementing something known as a Multilevel index. Basically create a nested indexing system, which although taking up data space, is very efficient, especially for sequential search practices where you do not wish to implement a tree outright. Create a set of outer indices which are more general, then link them to inner indices respectively, before moving onto stored data blocks.

Implementing this should not be too difficult and should drastically improve the amount of traversing being done. Hope this helps.